How do I get a review URL using the Google My Business API?
I am working on switching from using the Places API, which provides access to a couple of reviews for a business, to the Google My Business API, which provides all of the reviews. However, it seems that the GMB API does not include a URL that the user could click to see the review within Google (see https://maps.app.goo.gl/DXeWT9UJPdC9YbF4A for example). Is there a way to get this type of URL for a review pulled from the GMB API, using the reviewId or something along those lines?
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#Review provides a list of the fields available for a review (i.e. the aforementioned reviewId). Unfortunately, the URL I want is not included.
